# will segwit2x fork affect bitcoin cash

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

I read about the fact that segwit2x will split the BTC in BTC 2X. What will happen to BitCoin Cash BCH.

Answer (score 1):

BitCoin Cash and Bitcoin are two different blockchains. Technically, segwit2x won't affect the BTC blockchain nor the BCH blockchain (the only thing that might be affected is the price of each coin).

Comment: SegWit2x is a hard fork that will occur around November 16, 2017, and as a result of the hardfork there will be two chains, one will be Bitcoin Core (legacy Bitcoin) and the other will be the SegWit2x version of Bitcoin.: